# How to create table in Node.js script using data from a file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-table, client-server

Node.js script contains following route definition:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    fs.createReadStream('file.txt').pipe(csv()).on('data',(data)=>result.push(data)).on('end',() =>{
    .
    .
    .
    .
         let param1 = first;
         let param2 = second;
         let param3 = third;
         let param4 = forth;
    .
    .
    .
    res.write(html_table); // the task
    res.end();       
    });
})
```

Variables param? represent the data extracted from a file necessary for the table. Goal is to make this route return response which will contain html document with a table (or just a table). Let

```
param1 = "First parameter", param2 = "Second parameter"...
```

The response should be in following format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script></script>
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable" border="1px solid black">
        <tr>
            <th>Param1</th>
            <th>Param2</th>
            <th>Param3</th>
            <th>Param4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First parameter</td>
            <td>Second parameter</td>
            <td>Third parameter</td>
            <td>Forth parameter</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the best approach for solving this? Is it using cheerio package, or manipulating with client and server side javascript files?

Comment: Why don't you just render an html (ejs template engine maybe) file and pass the data in it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with EJS and was hoping for a another solution. Thank you for your advice tho.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a HTML file in your project folder. I created mine as `table.html` in directory `projectFolder/files/`. So the HTML file should look like this:

projectFolder/files/table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>#{tableData}</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that in our table.html we have `#{tableData}` text written inside table element. We will replace this `#{tableData}` text with our redered HTML in the router.

Next step is manipulating this HTML file in your router and send it to the client. To do this, we need **file system** module.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // Read HTML file
    fs.readFile('./files/table.html', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        // Redirect to error handler if there's any error
        if(err) return next(err);

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

        let tableData = {
            param1: 'value1',
            param2: 'value2',
            param3: 'value3'
        };

        // Write tableData object as a HTML table rows and columns
        let tableDataHead = '<tr>';
        let tableDataBody = '<tr>';
        for(let param in tableData) {
            tableDataHead += `<th>${param}</th>`;
            tableDataBody += `<td>${tableData[param]}</td>`;
        }
        tableDataHead += '</tr>';
        tableDataBody += '</tr>';

        // Concatenate tableDataHead and tableDataBody
        let tableDataHTML = tableDataHead + tableDataBody;

        // Replace #{tableData} text with our HTML data
        data = data.replace('#{tableData}', tableDataHTML);

        // Send rendered HTML file to the client
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

And the final response sended to client should look like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>param1</th>
            <th>param2</th>
            <th>param3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value1</td>
            <td>value2</td>
            <td>value3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the question includes a lot of code so I will give you a short set of steps that can help.

1. You need to read the file and save into a variable (Looks like you already doing that);
2. Now you need to use some kind of template engine to render the HTML page. I would advise you to use EJS, as a template engine.
3. Assuming that you have created an EJS template called `csv-table.ejs` file you need to call `render` function to render the data you have.
4. Let's say you have an array `data` variable, and you are using a template that is using `data` variable too, so you need to call `response.render('csv-table', { data });`

In the template you will need to loop over the `data` variable and render the table.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, much appreciated. I've done the first step already, just didn't include it in a code, because it's irrelevant to a problem. EJS would be helpful, but is there a way around because I've never used it. The only problems I'm having are  the parameters, otherwise a simple res.sendFile(__dirname + '/table.html') where table.html is a predefined file, would work.

Comment: Well you need to render the HTML somehow, EJS is the best way. You can render it just in place with your JS code as a string and then save it in a file and then send the file.

Comment: But I would strongly recomend you to use EJS, because it is very flexible and highly adopted. And it is very easy to use actually. Please mark the answer as correct if that solves your problem.